# What service could I use to programmatically (C#, ideally) upload and stream videos?

Tags: c#, video-streaming

I have a client that would like to add a feature to their application that allows an administrator to upload videos, which will be embedded in various content areas throughout the site. The whole thing should be transparent to the user, so he doesn't know he's using YouTube, or whatever service.

I see that YouTube has an API, but I don't know whether their TOS would allow my client to use their services transparently, in this manner. **What other video hosting/streaming services are there? That is my question.**

When I google for this, I just find a bunch of stuff about Netflix and Hulu (the consumer side of things), so I may simply need help with terminology so I can find the right keywords.

If you need more detail, just let me know! Thanks in advance for help with this.

Comment: Check out [PHPMotion](http://phpmotion.com/) - and hilariously, while I started posting this comment, I got a banner ad for a service called [Brightcove](http://go.brightcove.com/content/online-video-platform?c=70130000000jfhB) that appears to have a similar offering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much looking: I found some services.

- [zencoder](http://zencoder.com/) looks like the best!
- [brightcove](http://www.brightcove.com/en/online-video-platform/editions-and-pricing/) looks modern (thanks to commenter Val on my question), but maybe a bit pricey
- [xtream](http://www.xstream.dk/services/media-hosting) looks decent
- DIY with [Windows Streaming Media Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448620.aspx) :)
- [AudioVideoWeb](http://www.audiovideoweb.com/deliver-on-demand.php) looks okay
- [Astream](http://astream.com/stream/index.php/streaming-rates/us-usd-rates/on-demand-hosting-pricing-usd) looks okay

I hope this helps someone! I will probably go with zencoder (if my client decides they want this video feature they're asking about). If I do, I will come back here and update with my experience.